# i want to get all the text separately by tag with font size using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
    <p  id="page0002_para27" class="s1 f4 fs4">
<span id="page0002_13" class="f187 fs119">Math</span>
<span id="page0002_14" class="f4 fs119">Talk</span>
 <span class="left10">Children</span>

 continue discussing this scene and then 
    move to the next scene. Ask questions as needed to stimulate children to talk.
    </p>
```

I want to get all the texts under the p tag separately with their font size and color using java selenium. I don't want to hardcode it because I want to get all the texts from many p tag.

Comment: So what is your question? Where is your code? Exception/problem description?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
WebElement elementP = driver.findElementsById("page0002_para27");
List<WebElement> listOfSpans = driver.findElements(By.tagName("span"));
```

Or You could do same with css selector, but this is from top-of-my-head.

so You could do whatever You need to do with the following elements in `listOfSpans`

You can get the element color(Background color of element) by:

```
element.getCssValue("background-color");
```

You can get the element text attributes in example bellow:

```
System.out.println("font-size = "+ element.getCssValue("font-size"));
System.out.println("background = "+ element.getCssValue("background"));
System.out.println("line-height = "+ element.getCssValue("line-height"));
System.out.println("color = "+ element.getCssValue("color"));
System.out.println("font-family = "+ element.getCssValue("font-family"));
```

Hope this is what You're asking for,

Comment: I understood your point. via List<WebElement> listOfSpans = driver.findElements(By.tagName("span")); i am getting all the span text for all the p tag. now I want to get all the text under p tag except span tag text. because I have already all the span text and don't want it again.